# Airtable java API for android

Tags: java, android, airtable

I want to get/set data from an airtable with android app.

I'm using [Airtable java API](https://github.com/Sybit-Education/airtable.java) however I get this error:

[image]

I already added the following to `app/build.gradle` dependencies

```
implementation group: 'com.sybit', name: 'airtable.java', version: '0.2.0'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
```

I saw that there was an [android API](https://github.com/Sybit-Education/airtable.android) but it doesn't appear on [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sybit)

Is there a way to fix this error and properly use [Airtable Java API](https://github.com/Sybit-Education/airtable.java) with android ?

Comment: what precisely is your question ?

Comment: I would like to know how to fix this error, and being able to properly use Airtable Java API with android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lib [Airtable java API](https://github.com/Sybit-Education/airtable.java) is not available on android.

I did the same thing by using `HttpUrlConnection` library, refering to [Airtable Api doc](https://airtable.com/api)